# Module configuration screens not appearing

Tags: 7, installation

**Update 2020.05.29:**
I've rebuilt the whole of my development site from the ground up, and I've just run into this issue again. I set up git on my production site and cloned the file system (now Drupal 7.70) to my local MAMP environment. I'm using CiviCRM, so I've added civicrm.settings.php to .gitignore, as well as .htaccess, because the configuration on my live sever is different. I installed Drupal, CiviCRM, and a host of other modules no problem. The local site was running fine.

It became apparent that I really needed to test with some of the content from the production site in place to accomplish what I was trying to achieve, so I exported the database on production using Backup and Migrate and imported it locally. I got all the content in just fine, but Backup and Migrate's config screen itself started displaying an error, so I tried disabling and re-enabling the module. Backup and Migrate has now disappeared from the site menus. I've tried installing a couple of other modules, but they don't install correctly either. I see exactly the same behaviour I described below.

Module installation on the production site still works just fine. But whatever the problem is must come from the production database, 'cause neither settings.php nor .htaccess have changed from the version that was working just fine before the database import.

Any ideas?

**Original post:**
I'm relatively new to Drupal and I'm trying to make a local copy of a Drupal site 7 site I administer to test some new modules. I thought I had got it working, and the site seems to load without errors, but whenever I install a new module the configuration screens aren't available.

As an example, I've been trying to install the CKEditor module. The installer reports that it's completed OK, and it shows as enabled. If I try to create new content, the CKEditor toolbars appear on the editor as expected. But the configuration screen doesn't appear anywhere in Drupal's menus, and if I try to navigate to /admin/config/content/ckeditor it just resolves as /admin/config/content.

I've tried clearing the caches, and several different browsers, but nothing's making any difference. If I try creating a site from scratch in MAMP everything seems to work fine, and if I install on the live site it seems to work. It's only my local copy of the site that has the problem.

Drupal 7.69. MAMP 5.5, and the site is also using CiviCRM 5.22.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit 2020 02 21:** I'm still not getting anywhere with this, so a few more details of what I've been trying in the hope that someone can help me.

My development site is at

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devfolder
```

I have the following line in settings.php:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost:8888/devfolder';
```

And this in .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /devfolder
```

I've been playing about with variations on those, commenting lines out and reinstalling the affected modules, but it's not making any difference.

Comment: Does the project's `.htaccess` exist? Is `RewriteBase /` uncommented?

Comment: @leymannx Nope, 'RewriteBase /' is commented. I just tried uncommenting it, and the whole Drupal menubar disappeared.

Comment: Flush Drupal cache and re-check.

Comment: @leymannx I uncommented it, and then tried to flush the cache by going to /admin/config/development/performance, but that just got Not found. So I tried `RewriteBase /devfolder` and that does seem to load fine, but it didn't fix the problem. Even after completely removing the module, flushing the cache again, and reinstalling.

Comment: I've completely re-installed and run into the same problem as soon as imported the production database. Full details edited into the question.